# E/dalvikvm: Could not find class, nougat 7.1 os

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat

I got the following error in the Android Studio while running an app on  Android Nougat 7.1 OS

> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

What is the solution for this can any one help me on this

Thanks.

Comment: This error should occur on pre-lollipop device are you sure your running on Os 7

Comment: yes i am sure running on Os 7.1...

Comment: post your code xml and java one

Comment: sorry i can not post  code ((((copyright issue))))

Comment: without code i cnt help you sorry...

Comment: i appreciate your concern.

Comment: make sure that all library your using like android support or and design must be update to latest version and after that sync it and clean and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Build->Clean Project-> and run on the targeted device it should work. if still, it not working close project most probably it will work.

Answer (score 0):

update your libraries and SDK to use for OS 7